# display image above an other image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have a background image and I  want to perform functionality that when a button is clicked a second image is added above the background image. The image is added by click in my code but not above the background image. Furthermore my image is drag able and i want to make this drag able only inside the `div` if I mention `width` and `height`

For better explanation hare comes the code:

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/7p4F9/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#currentimage").after('<img id="dragable" src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />');
        $("#dragable").draggable()

    });    
});
```

Comment: user before instead after stmt

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7p4F9/14/

Comment: thanks Arun this is exactly what i want please tell me what happen when i click add image second time .Second instance is not dragable any more

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#currentimage").appendTo('<img id="dragable" src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />');
        $("#dragable").draggable()
    });    
});
```

You can use `.appendTo()`;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

html:

```
<div id="draggable" style="display:none;">  
  <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" /> 
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    var position =  $("#currentimage").offset();
     height = $("#currentimage" ).height();  
    //width = $("#currentimage" ).width();
     $("#dragable").css({ "display" : "block" , 'height':height, position : "absolute", "z-index" :"101", "background-color" : "#009ddf","opacity" : "0.9" } );  
    $("#dragable").offset($("#currentimage" ).offset());
    $("#dragable").draggable();
    });    
});
```

when click on image it will take the current image offset and overlays next image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#currentimage").html('<img id="dragable" src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />'+"<br /><img src=\"http://s25.postimg.org/v554s2umn/man_looking_at_sunset.jpg\" width=\"200px\" style=\"height: auto; z-index: 0;\"/>");
        $("#dragable").draggable()

    });    
});
```